Upgrade from Mojave to the latest macOS with option to revert
I have a MB Pro 13" 2018 which has been running Mojave (10.14.6). I have been considering upgrading to the newest macOS. However, I want to have a way back in case that the new macOS is not performing as I would expect. What is the best way to ensure that I can come back? I have been considering options:

Create disk image in recovery mode and should the need arise,
restore the whole disk image back.
EDIT I tried booting into restore mode but image cannot be taken of the Mac HD, it is greyed out. I assume it is because of the encryption. Can this still be done?
There are notes to download Mojave from Apple store but I am not so clear on how to proceed from there.
There are suggestions to backup using time machine and then use that to restore but I am not sure if Time Machine would restore the whole system back to Mojave.

Which is the best way to go?
Along those lines, upgrading to Sonoma from Mojave, is it better to first clean the system and do it from a clean system or it does not really matter and I can do it from the existing system?

Make a Time Machine backup, that's the recommended way to revert to a previous macOS version. I've used Time Machine a couple of times to do that and it's worked like a charm. It restores the whole disk. To be 100% sure the backup is usable, you could restore your latest backup to an external disk, just shut down your Mac, plug in the disk, start you Mac and immediately press and and hold Command-R, select "Restore from Time Machine" and select the external disk when requested which destination disk should the data be restored to (see https://support.apple.com/102655 for details).
